# RInside InternalFunction on a class, how to call the function from R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

I need to call R from C++ and I am using the excellent RInside / Rccp packages.
I am not an R specialist, this might explain my question and sorry if it's too obvious.

I made an object and a wrapper class, something similar to the Rinside examples/standard/rinside_interactive0.cpp. In this example it shows how to attach a method to an R attribute class.

```
wr.attr("class") = "Solver";    
R["Solver"] = wr;
... more code
R["names.Solver"] = Rcpp::InternalFunction(& Names); <-- Hot to call this one from R
```

Actually I never see a call from R to this function, and what would be the R syntax ? I though, using R.parseEval in such way:

```
R.parseEval("Solver.names()");
```

But this does not work and gives the error:

```
Error in Solver.names() : could not find function "Solver.names"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  Error evaluating: Solver.names()
```

My question is then how to call the Solver.names function in R (that is handled in the C++ code) ?
Note that the assign / retrieval function are working fine, maybe because they are somehow "primitive" ?

Thanks a lot
Franck

Answer (score 0):

I found out, I post in case someone is searching:

```
R.parseEval("names.Solver(Solver)");
```

Not very elegant to me .., it uses functionName.class(Object) ..

F.